# redirect output from dd command to /dev/null

Tags: linux, redirection

How to redirect output from dd command to `/dev/null`?

Answer (score 15):

If you want to redirect the data output, use the `of` argument:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/null count=1
```

If you want to redirect both the data output and the progress messages:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom count=1 >/dev/null 2>&1
```

If you want to save the data and throw away the messages:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=output_file count=1 2>/dev/null
```

In these examples `/dev/urandom` and the `count` argument are simply being used for demonstration.

Answer (score 3):

By default `dd` sends what it read from `if` to `stdout`, but usually (always?) one wants to redirect it to a file. Use the `of` parameter for that.

```
dd if=from of=to
```

So you want to replace `to` with `/dev/null`.